# Execute UITests In Different Order

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I have many test methods added to my project. I want to test by changing the order of tests each time.

For example if i have 3 test methods.
I want to run 6 tests like

i) 1 2 3

ii) 1 3 2

iii) 2 1 3

iv) 3 1 2

v) 2 3 1

vi) 3 2 1

How can i achive this in XCode?

Note: It is in means like test 1 creates setup things for test 2. Input or UI somethings like that. Thats why i need to keep a sequence

Answer (score 1):

Tests should not have any effect on state at all. And they should not depend on previous state either.

Running 1, 2, 3. Should have the exact same results as running 3, 2, 1.

Before running, each test should set up the required conditions that it is testing.

After running, each test should tear down the system so that there is nothing hanging around for the next test.

So, in answer to your question, I don't know if it's possible to specify an order... but you really shouldn't care what order they run in. If you do then that's a sign that your tests are not independent of each other.

Comment: It is in means like test 1 creates setup things for test 2. Input or UI somethings like that

Comment: Yes, that shouldn't happen. Test2 should not depend on test1 being run before it. If test2 needs to start at a particular part of the app then test2 should first set up the app so that it is at that part of the app and then continue from there. Each test should be entirely independent.